# How can I invert color for just a word and not the entire line?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

[image]

The issue that I like to have only the word "declined" color inversed and not all the line.

Any help?

```css
.invert {
  background-color: white;
  filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="line title-line highlight md uppercase invert">
  DECLINED
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Only apply your class to the part you want inverted?

Comment: Yes only the word "declined"

Comment: Is there a reason you're using a filter instead of setting the text and background colors?

Answer (score 1):

Use an inline element instead of a block-level element.

```css
.invert {
  background-color: white;
  filter: invert(100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="line title-line highlight md uppercase">
  <span class="invert">DECLINED</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted, wasn't even sure what the OP was asking.